# Select HTML Value is integer not displaying string

Tags: html, angularjs

I am running into an issue with a select being displayed

I have a samplemodel value that is an interger in the database. As of right now, I want to do a select as below, but I want it to display the string. The value will be displayed in my two way binding markup but when I select a string of yes, no, or na in the select value, it doesn't display the string or anything at all.

How do I get my value to display the string vs a int.

```
{{samplemodel}}
<select class="input-large input-large-altered" ng-model="samplemodel">
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
            <option value="2">No</option>
            <option value="3">NA</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using ng-options on your select. You can choose what you would like your model bound to that way.

Example:

```
 $scope.myArray = [
 {Val: 1, Display: 'Yes'},
 {Val: 2, Display: 'No'},
 {Val: 3, Display: 'NA'}
];
$scope.samplemodel = "Yes";
```

//Gives the Display string of the object

```
{{samplemodel}}
    <select class="input-large input-large-altered" ng-options="item.Display as item.Display for item in myArray" ng-model="samplemodel">
    </select>
```

OR

//Gives the val of the object

```
 <select class="input-large input-large-altered" ng-options="item.Val as item.Display for item in myArray" ng-model="samplemodel">
    </select>
```

OR
//Gives the whole object

```
 <select class="input-large input-large-altered" ng-options="item as item.Display for item in myArray" ng-model="samplemodel">
        </select>
```

Here is the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/lrRzk2xoadQt7rc46K4X?p=preview) to give you a full example.

Also to explain ng-options it works like so ng-options="[value] as [display] for [object] in [array]"

Comment: I am having a problem with myArray, I achieve it by added commas behind the curly braces, console.log it and see it, but when I use the select the options do not show up. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: Make sure you are using $scope.myArray

Comment: Also can you send me a code sample when you have that set so I can see if there is something missing.

Comment: I am using this 
                $scope.myArrray = [
               { Val: 1, Display: 'Yes' },
               { Val: 2, Display: 'No' },
               { Val: 3, Display: 'NA' }
                ];
                console.log($scope.myArrray); , then I pasted your select statements but the dropdown is still blank. Console.log returns 3 objects.

Comment: Also, How does your statement know to select the value of the integer but display the display? Still learning, so trying to understand it.

Comment: @epv, I have edited my answer above and added the plunkr to it. That is a working sample, please let me know if you need anymore help or have any questions.

Comment: Thank you ver much. I used the val of the object as I want it to select the val but display the display!

Answer (score 0):

**Update** Please use @Ohjay44's method as it is more performant. I will leave this up as it is still a valid optin.

You would have to use a filter:

**HTML**

```
{{samplemodel | stringFromInt}}
```

**JS**

```
app.filter('stringFromInt', function(){
    return function(input) {
      if (!input){
        return null;
      } else {
        return {1: 'Yes', 2: 'No', 3: 'NA'}[input];
      }
    }
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/DbQzDMSvCtyBWGSxvleU?p=preview

Comment: Brian don't you think there is a better way to accomplish this over a filter? A filter does work but it is going to constantly be running that filter while you are on the page, plus if he ever expands what is inside that select he has to remember to edit the filter. I believe ng-options would be a better solution.