# required not working for dropdown in html

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-class, requiredfieldvalidator

I am facing this issue with required tag. I want to make the quality field as mandatory without the valid option selected from the list the update billing button should not be enabled. Am I missing anything in the code? Please check the else condition part
I will be thankful for the help here.

```
else
{
    <div class="form-horizontal" ng-class="{'has-error':Edit.Quality.$invalid &&
      Edit.Quality.$dirty}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-lg-2 pull-left">Quality<span class="Imp">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <select id="Quality" name="Quality" class="form-control" style="width:170px" ng-model="vm.EditRef_UI.Quality" tooltip="Quality is required"
                        tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" required>
                    <option selected disabled value="">(Select a Timeline)</option>
                    <option value="Satisfactory">Satisfactory</option>
                    <option value="NotSatisfactory">Not Satisfactory</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

button code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="vm.Edit()" ng-disabled="Edit.$invalid" id="ticketEditbtn">Update Billing</button>
```

Comment: I don't see `required` in dropdown!

Comment: first one does not have it?

Comment: no. if condition drop doesn't have it. You can see the else part.

Comment: @beginner if that's the case, were you able to test if the code reaches the else statement?

Comment: Post the template with `form` declaration

Comment: @jmag yes it does enter else statement

Comment: @beginner how badly do you need the tool-tip="mouseenter"? I maybe wrong but can you test it without the mouseenter. It might be causing required to function only in mouseenter, where required checks if there is anything selected but needing the mouse with it which probably not what you want.

Comment: @jmag i dont think that is an issue. when i checked the code in DOM explorer what I noticed it the select is taking another option from database that is "<option value="? string:na ?"></option>" . Its taking string na from database which I had saved to keep quality as a non null  value. I want that option to be removed

Comment: @beginner Ah I see, the required is not firing because it is satisfied by the value being passed from somewhere. And now you that passed value removed.

Comment: @jmag How can i remove that?

Comment: @beginner it might be angular doing the string bindings but I don't know much about it. I came across  this article, it might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621028/select-html-value-is-integer-not-displaying-string

Comment: @jmag can you make your suggestion as answer so that I can choose that as an answer?

Comment: @beginner Were you able to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular does the string bindings as this  [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37621028/select-html-value-is-integer-not-displaying-string) suggested, thus satisfying the condition by the value being passed. This prevents the required from firing, thinking that there was value in the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

you can use loke this :

```
<select id="Quality" name="Quality" class="form-control" style="width:170px" ng-model="vm.EditRef_OCBUI.Quality" tooltip="Quality is required"
                    tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" required="required">
```

i wil be work

Comment: This is not working for me. Thanks for the answer :)